# How to make following layout with the help float,position

Tags: css, layout, html

...if possible without setting any ht/wd of A and B divs! A and B contain transparent images which overlap the bg main div.

|-------------------|

| --       Main -------   |

|--- ---------- ---- |

|-|A|  ---------|B|- |

|-------------------|

Thanks for response I am improving my que :: [sorry for confussion]

This is the following layout which I'm trying ..

```
<div id="main" style="width:200px;height:200px;overflow:hidden;">

    <div id="a" style="position:absolute;z-index:2;float:left;"> left side img </div>
    <div id="in" style="float:left;"> main image </div>
    <div id="b" style="position:absolute;z-index:2;float:left;"> rt side image </div>

</div>
```

where "a" and "b" contain the transparent iamges which need to overlap the "in" div image.

Is it possible?

Comment: You want to create 3 column liquid  layout with header and footer? please explain your problem

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have following layout structure

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

If I understood your question, you want to make a and b transparent without exact width and height. Right?  No it's impossible without exact **width** at least. So, you need to write following css rules.

Here are the some variants

**% values  (Width:20%. height100%)**

```
.main {width:100%; height:100%}
.a {width:20%; height:100%; background-image:transparent.png; float:left;}
.b {width:20%; height:100%; background-image:transparent.png; float:right;}
```

**OR % values (Width:20%. height20%) and with exact positioning (you can place whatever you want instead 50px it's distance from top and left/right for a/b divs)**

```
.main {width:100%; height:100%}
.a {width:20%; height:20%; background-image:transparent.png; float:left; position:absolute; top:50px; left:50px;}
.b {width:200px; height:200px; background-image:transparent.png; float:right; position:absolute; top:50px; right:50px;}
```

**OR pixel values**

```
.main {width:100%; height:100%}
.a {width:200px; height:200px; background-image:transparent.png; float:left; position:absolute; top:50px; left:50px;}
.b {width:20%; height:20%; background-image:transparent.png; float:right; position:absolute; top:50px; right:50px;}
```